# Closed form of iterated function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, collatz-conjecture

It can be easily calculated that performing the operation $(3x+1)$ on a number m, k times yields the result $(3^k)(m)+(3^k -1)/2$

I want to calculate a closed formula for performing the related operation $(3x+1)/2$ on a number m, k times but can't seem to find it.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1. What is the fixed point of this operation, i.e. for what $x$ do we have $(3x+1)/2 = x$?
2. How does your operation affect displacement from the fixed point?

Comment: I see that it fixes the point -1 as well the fact that each iteration yields a closer approximation to 3^k/2^k but I cant find the nice closed form form as I did earlier.

Comment: The operation multiplies displacement from the fixed point by $3/2$.  After $k$ iterations, that displacement, initially $m-1$, has become $(3/2)^k (m-1)$.  So what point has that displacement from $-1$?